# % operator seems not working in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to count the number of 3 consecutive wins of team A and B. It seems to be always getting into the final ifs. Not when consecutivas equals 3,6,9...

```
  var consecutivasA = 0;
  var consecutivasB = 0;
  var plusA = 0;
  var plusB = 0;

  for (var i = 2; i <= 30; i++) {
    var row = values[i];

      if (row[3] > row[4]) { 
        consecutivasA++;
        consecutivasB = 0;
      }
      else if (row[3] < row[4]) {
        consecutivasB++;
        consecutivasA = 0;
      }
      else {
        consecutivasA = 0;
        consecutivasB = 0;
      }

      if (consecutivasB % 3 == 0) { plusB++; } 
      if (consecutivasA % 3 == 0) { plusA++; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it you also increment when consecutivas is 0, because 0 % 3 is also 0. This example writes the outcome of the example data to the log.

```
function consecutivasMod () {
  var consecutivasA = 0;
  var consecutivasB = 0;
  var plusA = 0;
  var plusB = 0;
  values=[
    [0,0,0,1,0],    [0,0,0,1,0],    [0,0,0,1,0],    [0,0,0,0,1],    [0,0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,1],    [0,0,0,0,0],    [0,0,0,0,0],    [0,0,0,0,0],    [0,0,0,0,2],
    [0,0,0,0,3],    [0,0,0,0,4],    [0,0,0,0,5],    [0,0,0,0,6],    [0,0,0,0,7],
     ]
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var row = values[i];

     if (row[3] > row[4]) { 
       consecutivasA++;
       consecutivasB = 0;
     }
     else if (row[3] < row[4]) {
       consecutivasB++;
       consecutivasA = 0;
     }
     else {
       consecutivasA = 0;
       consecutivasB = 0;
     }

     if (consecutivasB>0&&(consecutivasB % 3) == 0) { plusB++; } 
     if (consecutivasA>0&&(consecutivasA % 3) == 0) { plusA++; }
  }
 Logger.log ("consecutivasA "+plusA);
 Logger.log ("consecutivasB "+plusB);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Log the values of consecutivasA and B right before the final ifs... I suspect strongly that your values are always zero due to an earlier logic error.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about doing this another way--instead of using the logic you provide, which I think just checks if the total number of wins by Team A or Team B are divisible by 3 (which does not necessarily say anything about whether the wins are *consecutive*), I would try the following:

Run through your array and write an if statement checking if Team A won in a particular place. If yes, check if it won in n+1 and n+2 as well. If so, increment plusA.

Run through your array again and write an if statement checking if Team B won in a particular place. If yes, check if it won in n+1 and n+2 as well. If so, increment plusB.

**NOTE:** Check only until two entries before the final entry in your array, as going beyond that would return an array size error.

Comment: Thanks, I thought to do it that way also but what you said about my way isn't true, by putting consecutivasA and B to 0 when they loose or tie I'm getting the goal.